# How to submit a dropdown box value in php without using submit

Tags: php, javascript

How to submit a dropdown box value in php without using submit and javascript is that possible or am i wrong.also i dont want to use following way

```
document.forms["adminorder"].action = "../controller/vieworderprocess.php?name="+combine;
document.forms["adminorder"].submit();
```

Comment: why not submit? you can use ajax, but it isn't less complex than plain submit.

Comment: use onchange event for the select. like: <select onchange='document.forms["adminorder"].submit()'>

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet `<select onchange='this.form.submit()'>` looks much simpler

Comment: @mpapec: indeed, but I tried to stay close to OP's code :-)

Comment: @mpapec How to use ajax i don`t know ajax.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.location.href="../controller/vieworderprocess.php?name="+combine";

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use ajax... is javascript, but you can send a value to a server in async mode... without submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You cant submit a form without either having a submit form or thorough using the submit() function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using j query form [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method or java script form [submit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method without submit buttons.Or you can use Ajax for sending the necessary values without submit method.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript form submit method.

Comment: If you dont want to use submit method try with ajax